# Evaluating $\int _1^3\:\sqrt{x^4+1} \;dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

A friend of mine asked me this question, given by a book with many difficult math problems. And then, I saw that is quite interesting to start by trying to evaluate the problem by the substitution of $x^4+1$, so we can call it **u.** But, unfortunately, this couldn't help me, since the integral just got harder, as I found a new integral in terms of **u**, that has the annoying $4x$ messing up with this possible solution.

So, finally, after failing with Wolfram Alpha, Symbolab, and others, I came here to ask you guys, how can I solve it? $$\int _1^3\:\sqrt{x^4+1} \ \  dx$$

Also, it even gets more difficult when he asks:

What is the value of $x$, since $$\int _1^3\:\sqrt{x^4+1} \ \ dx\ge \frac{2x}{3}$$

Thank you all for spending some time analyzing my question!

Comment: Be careful with your second integral: the $x$ on the right-hand side is completely unrelated to the $x$s on the left-hand side! (I'm not sure your second expression is meaningful, actually.)

Comment: I sense a strog smell of elliptic integral.

Comment: Mathematica says the numerical answer is about 8.98005623469252857877121527304; it can't find a nice approximation to this number.

Comment: One usually tries $u$-substitution when the integrand contains a factor to correspond with $\mathrm{d}u$.  It is possible a trignometric or other "special function" substitution will be required.

Comment: And the exact answer is, as simply as Mathematica can make it, $\frac{1}{3} \sqrt{2} \left(-1+3 \sqrt{41}+(1+i) F\left(\left.i \sinh
   ^{-1}\left(\sqrt[4]{-1}\right)\right|-1\right)-(1+i) F\left(\left.i \sinh ^{-1}\left(3
   \sqrt[4]{-1}\right)\right|-1\right)\right)$, where $F$ is the elliptic integral of the first kind.

Comment: Well, it seems that Mr Sangchul Lee is right by mentioning elliptic integrals.
So, Mr Patrick Stevens, it seems that is a bunch of things to do with this integral until it gives the correct answer. Therefore, let's focus in a way to do correct substitutions, and then confirm this result. 

Thank you, guys!

Comment: Here's what I get...$$\frac{1}{3} \left(-K\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)-\sqrt{2}+3 \sqrt{82}+F\left(2 \tan ^{-1}(3)|\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\int_1^3\sqrt{x^4+1}~dx$

$=\int_1^3x^2\sqrt{1+\dfrac{1}{x^4}}~dx$

$=\int_1^3x^2\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n(2n)!}{4^n(n!)^2(1-2n)x^{4n}}~dx$

$=\int_1^3\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n(2n)!x^{2-4n}}{4^n(n!)^2(1-2n)}~dx$

$=\left[\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n(2n)!x^{3-4n}}{4^n(n!)^2(1-2n)(3-4n)}\right]_1^3$

$=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{27(-1)^n(2n)!}{324^n(n!)^2(2n-1)(4n-3)}-\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n(2n)!}{4^n(n!)^2(2n-1)(4n-3)}$